# I am using smarty template inside my php project its working fine on php 7.4 but not working on php 8

Tags: php, smarty

you can see there are many missing values in php 8 or 8.1.
how can i run this on php 8 shoud i upgrade smarty or is there some other issue with the code.
I updated the smarty library in the code but it did'nt worked at all moreover it started giving error.

Smarty Object returns this in 7.4:

```
TshSmarty Object
(
    [RootDir] => /home2/mjollnir/public_html/dev_mjollnirgroup/
    [TemplateDir] => /home2/mjollnir/public_html/dev_mjollnirgroup/template/
    [CompileDir] => /home2/mjollnir/public_html/dev_mjollnirgroup/compile/
    [CacheDir] => /home2/mjollnir/public_html/dev_mjollnirgroup/compile/cache/
    [IsCached] => 
    [IsCompileCheck] => 1
    [IsForceCompile] => 
    [template_dir] => /home2/mjollnir/public_html/dev_mjollnirgroup/template/
    [compile_dir] => /home2/mjollnir/public_html/dev_mjollnirgroup/compile/
    [config_dir] => configs
    [plugins_dir] => Array
        (
            [0] => plugins
        )

    [debugging] => 
    [error_reporting] => 
    [debug_tpl] => 
    [debugging_ctrl] => NONE
    [compile_check] => 1
    [force_compile] => 
    [caching] => 
    [cache_dir] => /home2/mjollnir/public_html/dev_mjollnirgroup/compile/cache/
    [cache_lifetime] => 3600
    [cache_modified_check] => 
    [php_handling] => 0
    [security] => 
  
)



and returns in PHP 8:


TshSmarty Object
(
    [template_dir] => templates
    [compile_dir] => templates_c
    [config_dir] => configs
    [plugins_dir] => Array
        (
            [0] => plugins
        )

    [_cache_include] => 
    [_cache_including] => 
    [RootDir] => 
    [TemplateDir] => 
    [CompileDir] => 
    [CacheDir] => 
    [IsCached] => 
    [IsCompileCheck] => 1
    [IsForceCompile] => 
)
```

Comment: _"shoud i upgrade smarty or is there some other issue with the code"_ - You ask if you should upgrade, but write in the sentence after that you've already done that? Well, it's always good to update/upgrade your dependencies (for multiple reasons). We can't know if there are any other issues with your code since we haven't seen it. Have you checked the compatibility of the Smarty version you're using? Have you checked their github issues (including the closed ones) to see if others have the same issue?

Comment: Currently using  smarty version 2.6.6 @M.Eriksson

Comment: From the [Smarty page](https://www.smarty.net/): "_Smarty 4.1.0 is released! This version adds PHP 8.1 compatibility._" So, yes updating Smarty is a good idea

Comment: 2.6.6? I can't even find that version in their Github repo. The oldest I can find is 2.6.24, which was created way back in 2014, so your version is even older. How exactly did you upgrade it? Or are you not using the official smarty library for PHP? I'm more surprised that it was still working in PHP 7.4. You should **definitely** start updating your dependencies on regular basis. It's not just about compatibility, but libraries get security updates as well.

Comment: My personal advice: Avoid php template engines and forget about such senseless dependencies. I know, that this advice may not help you. But what about kicking out this dependency and follow the separation of concerns principle. Then you will notice very quickly that php template engines are simply superfluous.